# Is there a scripture affirming the begetting of the Word?

Tags: trinity, bible-translation, greek

John's prologue does support the begetting of the Word by using the term " only-begotten" but bible scholars nowadays almost always consider it as a mistranslation of the Greek word " monogenes".

So the question really revolves around the said word " monogenes". Is there a Biblical, Historical and Linguistic proof for it to be translated as " only begotten"?

The NASB is a very current  English Bible version that still translate "monogenes" as only begotten. Therefore, my question is answerable.

Answer (score 4):

The following is a list of multitudes of Greek words that share the same suffix -γενής, each with possesses the sense of “born”/ “begotten”:

ἀφρογενής = “foam-born”

Αἰγυπτογενής = “born of an Egyptian”

αἰθρηγενής = “born in Aether (clear sky)”

ἁλιγενής = “sea-born” (also, ποντογενής; θαλασσογενής)

ἀλλογενής = “born of another [race]”

ἀρτιγενής = “just now born”

Ἀσιαγενής = “Asiatic born” (also, Ἀσιατογενής)

Ἀτλαγενής = “born of Atlas”

αὐθιγενής = “born here”

βοηγενής = “born of an ox”

βραδυγενής = “late-born” (also, ὀψιγενής)

γηγενής = “earth-born”

Δηλογενής = “born in Delos”

διδυμογενής = “twin-born” (born as a twin) (also, ὁμηγενής)

διγενής = “double-born” (born as both sexes; androgynous)

Διογενής = “born of Dio” (also known as “Zeus”)

Διθυραμβογενής = “born of Dithyramb” (also known as “Dionysius”)

δρακοντογενής = “born of a dragon”

δυσγενής = “low-born” (also, νοθαγενής)

ἑβδομαγενής = “born on the seventh day”

ἐγγενής = “inborn”; “innate”
ἑλειογενής = “marsh-born”

ἐνδογενής = “born in the house” (also, οἰκογενής)

εὐηγενής = “well-born”

ἠπειρογενής = “born or living in the mainland (esp. of Greece)”

θεαγενής = “god-born” (also, θεηγενής; θειογενής; θεογενής)

Ἰδογενής = “born on Mount Ida”

Ἰνδογενής = “born in India”

ἰθαγενής = “legally born”

κακογενής = “evil-born”; “base-born”

κογχογενής = “born from a shell”

Κοιογενής = “born of Koios”

κρατογενής = “head-born”

κρυφογενής = “secretly born” (also, κυθηγενής)

Κυπρογενής = “born in Cyprus”

Λητογενής = “born of Leto”

Λυκηγενής = “born in Lycia”

μελιηγενής = “ash-born”

μεταγενής = “born after”

Νειλογενής = “born in the Nile”

νεογενής = “new-born”

νυμφαγενής = “born of a nymph” (also, νυμφογενής)

ὀφιογενής = “born of a serpent”

ὀμβρηγενής = “born in the rain”

ὀνειρογενής = “born of a dream”

ὀρειγενής = “mountain-born”

παλαιγενής = “born of old”; “born long ago”

πατρογενής = “father born”; “begotten of the father”

Περσογενής = “born in Persia”

πετρηγενής = “rock-born” (also, πετρογενής)

πρεσβυγενής = “first-born”; “eldest-born” (also, πρωτογενής)

προγενής = “born before” (also, προσγενής; προσθαγενής; προτερηγενής)

Πυλοιγενής = “born in Pylos”

πυριγενής = “born in fire” (also, πυρογενής)

Σουσιγενής = “born at Susa”

συγγενής = “born with”; “congenital”

Ταρσογενής = “born at Tarsus”

τετραγενής = “born four times”

τριγενής = “born three times”; “thrice-born”

Τριτογενής = “born of Triton”

ὑδογενής = “born in water”

ὑλιγενής = “born in the forest” (also, ὑλογενής)

ὑπερευγενής = “exceedingly well-born”

φοινικογενής = “born in Phoenicia”

Notice the suffix of all the words. It is -γενής, just like in the word μονογενής.

---

As for a verse that confirms the eternal begetting, aside from those containing μονογενής, consider [John 8:42](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?b=Jhn&c=8&t=KJV#conc/42), in which it is written,

> εἶπεν οὖν αὐτοῖς ὁ Ἰησοῦς Εἰ ὁ θεὸς πατὴρ ὑμῶν ἦν ἠγαπᾶτε ἂν ἐμέ ἐγὼ γὰρ ἐκ τοῦ θεοῦ ἐξῆλθον καὶ ἥκω οὐδὲ γὰρ ἀπ᾽ ἐμαυτοῦ ἐλήλυθα ἀλλ᾽ ἐκεῖνός με ἀπέστειλεν
>
> Therefore, Yeshua a said to them, "If God were your father, you would love me, for I came out of God and have arrived. For neither have I come of myself, but the same sent me."

In *De Trinitate* ("On the Trinity"), Hilary of Poitiers strives to refute numerous heresies, one of which denied the force of the aforementioned scripture. In response to these heretics, he wrote,

> Postremo quod dixit: Ex Patre exivi, et veni (John 8:42), utrum ambiguitatem reliquerit, quin intelligeretur non aliunde quam ex Patre esse quod Deus est? Ex Patre enim exiens, neque aliam nativitatis habuit naturam, neque nullam: sed eum sibi testatur auctorem, ex quo se profitetur exisse. De his autem demonstrandis atque intelligendis posterior mihi sermo est.
>
> (Pending my English translation)  See link below for Schaff's translation.

Source: *De Trinitate* ("On the Trinity"), Book VI, §16. | [English](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf209.ii.v.ii.vi.html?scrBook=John&scrCh=8&scrV=42#ii.v.ii.vi-p62.1) | [Latin](http://www.clerus.org/bibliaclerusonline/pt/grl.htm) |

---

[This pdf](http://ateret-tiferet.com/exegesis/A_List_of_New_Testament_Verses_Containing_Exerchomai_and_Ex-Ek.pdf) contains a list of all the NT verses in which we find a conjugation of the verb ἐξέρχομαι followed by the preposition ἐκ/ ἐξ. What this list demonstrates is that Yeshu'a must have actually come out of God --- not in a figurative way, nor by simply being sent (which is expressed elsewhere by another Greek phrase: ἐγὼ παρὰ τοῦ θεοῦ ἐξῆλθον, cp. John 16:27), but actually, by a spiritual generation.

The peculiar thing about this Greek phrase is that it is also used in the LXX to indicate offspring being begotten from a father (cp. [Gen. 15:4](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?b=Gen&c=15&v=4&t=KJV#conc/4): ἐξελεύσεται ἐκ; [Gen. 17:6](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?b=Gen&c=17&v=6&t=KJV#conc/6): ἐκ...ἐξελεύσονται; [Gen. 35:11](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?t=KJV&b=Gen&c=35&v=11&x=55&y=15#conc/11): ἐκ...ἐξελεύσονται; [Gen. 46:26](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?b=Gen&c=46&v=26&t=KJV#conc/26): ἐξελθόντες ἐκ) and coming forth from a mother's womb ([Job 1:21](http://www.blbclassic.org/Bible.cfm?b=Job&c=1&v=21&t=KJV#conc/21): ἐξῆλθον ἐκ), both acts of generation.

Commenting about the Greek phrase ἐκ τοῦ θεοῦ ἐξῆλθον in John 8:42, [John Gill](http://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/gills-exposition-of-the-bible/john-8-42.html) notes,

> the former of these phrases is observed by many learned men to be used by the Septuagint, of a proper natural birth, as in (Gen. 15:4, 35:11); and here designs the eternal generation of Christ, as the Son of God, being the only begotten of the Father, and the Son of the Father in truth and love; and the other is to be understood of his mission from him, as Mediator:

In his commentary on John 8:42, [Henry Alford](http://www.studylight.org/com/hac/view.cgi?bk=42&ch=8) notes,

> ἥκω conveys the result of ἐξῆλθον, as Meyer; who also remarks that mere sending will not exhaust ἐξῆλθον, which must be taken metaphysically, of the proceeding forth of the Eternal Son from the essence of the Father.

Comment: Hey, this answer would be better if you had some examples to make your case.  